# gradle see output for model.components.binaries.all

Tags: c++, debugging, gradle

I have

```
all {
    if (toolChain in Gcc) {
        cppCompiler.args "--std=c++11",
        "-I", "${lib_base_path}",
        "-I", "${lib_base_path}${File.separator}include",
        "-I", "${jni_base_path}",
        "-I", "/usr/local/inclue/eigen3"
        linker.args "-L", "${lib_linker_path}", "-lcpp_pose",
            "-Wl,-rpath,${lib_linker_path}"
    } else if (toolChain in Clang) {
        cppCompiler.args "--std=c++11",
        "-I", "${lib_base_path}",
        "-I", "${lib_base_path}${File.separator}include",
        "-I", "${jni_base_path}",
        "-I", "/usr/local/inclue/eigen3"
        linker.args "-L", "${lib_linker_path}", "-lcpp_pose",
            "-Wl,-rpath,${lib_linker_path}"
    } else {
        throw GradleException("Tool chain " + toolChain +
                              " is not supported.")
    }
}
```

as a section in my gradle.build file. However when gradle goes to build, I get

```
fatal error: 'Eigen/Core' file not found
#include <Eigen/Core>
         ^
1 error generated.
```

The /usr/local/include/eigen3 in the include flags should take care of this issue. To debug what gradle is using to build my binaries I would like to see the compile statement to debug. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

After rethinking what to Google I found this post:

https://discuss.gradle.org/t/debug-native-output/9508/2

The answer being in:

> We generate an options file (build/tmp//options.txt) that has all of the common arguments. You can use -i or --info to see just the command line that's being executed (per source file) as well.
>   There's a hook withArguments...